WPF Dynamically add columns using a pre-defined DataTemplate
I have a DataTemplate defined in the resources area of my custom WPF UserControl which renders a bunch of colored squares for a bunch of "flags". The goal is to dynamically add columns to GridView that share the same DataTemplate, but have different bindings for the ItemsSource={Binding Flags} property. Note that I don't know ahead of time which columns need to be dynamically added, otherwise I could just define them all in XAML.
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FlagColumnTemplate">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Flags}">
            ...
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="gridView">
             <GridViewColumn Header="Static Column 1" />
             <!-- Additional columns are added dynamically in code-behind -->
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>

For this example, I am adding the new columns dynamically to my GridView in code behind like this (this is to simplify, in reality the dynamic columns would be based on data inside the view model):
var flagDataTemplate = Resources["FlagColumnTemplate"] as DataTemplate;

var newColumn1 = new GridViewColumn() { Header = "Dynamic Column 1", CellTemplate = flagDataTemplate };
var newColumn2 = new GridViewColumn() { Header = "Dynamic Column 2", CellTemplate = flagDataTemplate };

gridView.Columns.Add(newColumn1);
gridView.Columns.Add(newColumn2);

// Somehow modify the "Flags" binding in the DataTemplate for each new column.

My goal is to set the ItemsSource="{Binding Flags}" binding such that each new dynamic column has its own object for Flags instead of the same one for all columns.
I tried a MultiBinding paired with a multi value converter to hopefully set the items source based on the column header for each column's DataTemplate, but that didn't work. The problem is that in the Live Visual Tree GridViewColumn doesn't exist, so there's no way to get to a GridViewColumn from inside a CellTemplate via RelativeSource.
I also see no way to modify the bindings inside flagDataTemplate when creating the new columns, but perhaps I'm missing something...

You should use a DataGrid instead of the ListView. This enables you to use a DataTable as data source for the DataGrid. Now you can modify the DataTable to add/remove columns to the DataGrid dynamically.

@BionicCode Sure, but the problem still remains that the dynamic columns have to use the pre-existing DataTemplate and the binding needs to be column-specific -- thus also set dynamically.

I would define a as a string. Substitute binding property name in that and xamlreader.parse into a column

How can you predefine column templates when you don't know what columns you have to display? You would let the DataGrid auto-generate the columns.

@BionicCode The columns don't just contain a simple value that can be displayed as a string. It uses a DataTemplate to basically render a list of entities (flags) as clickable squares in the row. All the new dynamic columns would display these flags via the same data template, but I want each column to have its own items source. This is explained in the original description.

@Andy Thanks for the suggestion. I attempted this, but the data template contains static resources (converters) and also a mouse event bound to the host control and those can't be resolved by the live xamlreader.parse method.

I understand. But you can handle the DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn event. Here you can replace the default DataGridTextColumn with a DataGridTemplateColumn.  You can prepare a DataGridTemplateColumn and add it to a ResourceDictionary. The column could have the DataTemplate assigned to the DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate property. You can get this resource from the DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn event to perform the substitution.

You can even compose the column's visuals on the fly if really needed. I think that's the easiest solution when your goal is to have a dynamic, yet customizable table.

Composing the view on the fly might have to be it... I haven't found a way to swap bindings on a DataTemplate after the fact without xamlreader.parse, which I cant use because the template has events and other external resources. I'll give datatable some more consideration, but that might be a drastic change to the app look just for this feature.

I understand that you have your reasons to stick with the GridView. So, I decided to post a simple solution that allows you to change any number of bindings within the GridViewColumn.CellTemplate dynamically. The only requirement is that you have to name the elements that have a dynamic Binding value. You also have to use the GridViewDynamicColumn, which extends the normal GridViewColumn. You can mix both types or interchange them without breaking anything. GridViewColumn is simply ignored.
Usage
For each Binding you want to replace in the DataTemplate you have to define a BindingInfo that specifies the new Binding, the element name of the element that is the binding target and the target property:
<UserControl.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="FlagColumnTemplate">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="FlagItemsView" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Flags}">
            ...
    </ItemsControl>

    <TextBlock x:Name="Label" 
               Text="{Binding LabelValue}" />
  </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<!-- Example replaces the bindings on two elements contained within the above CellTemplate -->
<ListView x:Name="FlagsView">
  <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">

    <!-- Register the attached behavior with each ListViewItem -->
    <Setter Property="local:GridViewHelper.IsDynamicCellContentEnabled"
            Value="True" />
    </Style>
  </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

  <ListView.View>
    <GridView x:Name="gridView">
      <GridViewColumn Header="Static Column 1"
                      CellTemplate="{StaticResource FlagColumnTemplate}" />

      <!-- Override CellTemplate bindings at XAML level -->
      <GridViewDynamicColumn Header="Dynamic Column 1"
                             CellTemplate="{StaticResource FlagColumnTemplate}">
        <local:BindingInfo TargetName="FlagItemsView" 
                           Binding="{Binding OtherFlags}"
                           TargetProperty="{x:Static ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty}" />
        <local:BindingInfo TargetName="Label"
                           Binding="{Binding Id}"                            
                           TargetProperty="{x:Static TextBlock.TextProperty}" />
      </GridViewDynamicColumn>

      <!-- Additional columns are added dynamically in code-behind -->
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>

/*** Override template bindings at C# level ***/

var flagDataTemplate = Resources["FlagColumnTemplate"] as DataTemplate;

var newColumn = new GridViewDynamicColumn() 
{ 
  Header = "Dynamic Column 2", 
  CellTemplate = flagDataTemplate 
};

// Assuming that the data items of ListView.ItemsSource are 
// of fictional type RowDataItem
var newBinding = new Binding(nameof(RowDataItem.OtherFlags));

var bindingInfo = new BindingInfo(binding: newBinding, targetName: "FlagItemsView", targetProperty: ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty);
column.BindingInfos.Add(bindingInfo);
gridView.Columns.Add(newColumn);

// Force ListView to reload all item containers. 
// Because ListView uses UI virtualization this will not be too expensive.
// This way we only have to care about the visible items.
// Each ListViewItem.Loaded event will trigger the update of the cell template bindings.
// This ensures that the realized item containers are always up to date without significantly impacting the overall performance.
this.FlagsView.Items.Refresh();

Implementation
GridViewHelper.cs
Because ListView uses UI virtualization a row-based cell update will not be too expensive.
This way we are automatically dealing with only the currently visible item containers (instead of always iterating over all rows).
Each ListViewItem.Loaded event will trigger the update of the cell template bindings.
This ensures that the realized item containers are always up to date without significantly impacting the overall performance.
In this context, leaving UI virtualization enabled is highly recommended.
public sealed class GridViewHelper : DependencyObject
{
  public static bool GetIsDynamicCellContentEnabled(DependencyObject attachingElement)
    => (bool)attachingElement.GetValue(IsDynamicCellContentEnabledProperty);

  public static void SetIsDynamicCellContentEnabled(DependencyObject attachingElement, bool value)
    => attachingElement.SetValue(IsDynamicCellContentEnabledProperty, value);

  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDynamicCellContentEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "IsDynamicCellContentEnabled",
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(GridViewHelper),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), OnIsDynamicCellContentEnabledChanged));

  private static void OnIsDynamicCellContentEnabledChanged(DependencyObject attachingElement, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (attachingElement is not ListViewItem listViewItem)
    {
      throw new ArgumentException($"Only {typeof(ListViewItem).FullName} supported.", nameof(attachingElement));
    }

    bool isEnabled = (bool)e.NewValue;
    if (isEnabled)
    {
      listViewItem.AddHandler(FrameworkElement.LoadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnListViewItemLoaded));
    }
    else
    {
      listViewItem.RemoveHandler(FrameworkElement.LoadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnListViewItemLoaded));
    }
  }

  private static void OnListViewItemLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var listViewItem = (ListViewItem)sender;

    if (!TryFindVisualChildElement(listViewItem, out GridViewRowPresenter gridViewRowPresenter))
    {
      return;
    }

    int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(gridViewRowPresenter);
    for (int cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < childrenCount; cellIndex++)
    {
      if (gridViewRowPresenter.Columns[cellIndex] is not GridViewDynamicColumn column)
      {
        continue;
      }

      DependencyObject contentPresenter = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(gridViewRowPresenter, cellIndex);

      foreach (BindingInfo bindingInfo in column.BindingInfos)
      {
        if (TryFindVisualChildElementByName(contentPresenter, bindingInfo.TargetName, out FrameworkElement bindingTarget))
        {
          BindingBase propertyBinding = bindingInfo.Binding;
          _ = bindingTarget?.SetBinding(bindingInfo.TargetProperty, propertyBinding);
        }
      }
    }
  }

#region Helper

  private static bool TryFindVisualChildElementByName<TChild>(
    DependencyObject parent,
    string childElementName,
    out TChild? resultElement) where TChild : FrameworkElement
  {
    resultElement = null;

    if (parent is System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup popup)
    {
      parent = popup.Child;
      if (parent == null)
      {
        return false;
      }
    }

    for (int childIndex = 0; childIndex < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); childIndex++)
    {
      DependencyObject childElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, childIndex);
      if (childElement is FrameworkElement uiElement
        && uiElement.Name.Equals(childElementName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      {
        resultElement = uiElement as TChild;
        return true;
      }

      if (TryFindVisualChildElementByName(childElement, childElementName, out resultElement))
      {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }

  private static bool TryFindVisualChildElement<TChild>(DependencyObject parent, out TChild? resultElement)
    where TChild : DependencyObject
  {
    resultElement = null;

    if (parent is System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup popup)
    {
      parent = popup.Child;
      if (parent == null)
      {
        return false;
      }
    }

    for (int childIndex = 0; childIndex < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); childIndex++)
    {
      DependencyObject childElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, childIndex);
      if (childElement is TChild child)
      {
        resultElement = child;
        return true;
      }

      if (TryFindVisualChildElement(childElement, out resultElement))
      {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }

#endregion Helper
}

GridViewDynamicColumn.cs
Enable XAML BindingInfo definitions.
[ContentProperty(nameof(GridViewDynamicColumn.BindingInfos))]
public class GridViewDynamicColumn : GridViewColumn
{
  public BindingInfoCollection BindingInfos { get; } = new BindingInfoCollection();
}

BindingInfo.cs
Data structure to hold the information of the binding to replace.
public class BindingInfo
{
  public BindingInfo()
  {
  }

  public BindingInfo(BindingBase binding, string targetName, DependencyProperty targetProperty)
  {
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(binding);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(targetName);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(targetProperty);

    this.Binding = binding;
    this.TargetName = targetName;
    this.TargetProperty = targetProperty;
  }

  public BindingBase Binding { get; set; }
  public string TargetName { get; set; }
  public DependencyProperty TargetProperty { get; set; }
}

BindingInfoCollection.cs
Collection to enable XAML BindingInfo definitions.
public class BindingInfoCollection : List<BindingInfo>
{
  public BindingInfoCollection()
  {
  }

  public BindingInfoCollection(IEnumerable<BindingInfo> collection) : base(collection)
  {
  }

  public BindingInfoCollection(int capacity) : base(capacity)
  {
  }
}


Thank you so much for the sample code, I will try it. I did end up customizing it all into a single column containing evenly spaced ItemsControl for each additional dynamic "column".  So it does eventually look like I wanted it to, it's just under a single column header.
Your solution might actually be it for doing this properly in a ListView+GridView. It should be very helpful for others.

Too bad you didn't need it anymore ;) No, I'm happy you found a solution that you are happy with. All the best.
